# Which is a good library/framework to use for single sign on in a java web app with ADFS 2 integration

Tags: java, single-sign-on, adfs2.0, shibboleth, openam

We are currently exploring **OpenAM** & **Shibboleth**.

Our app is not built using Spring and we are not exploring use of Spring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of libraries, the only one I know of is [OpenSAML](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/Home).

I wouldn't call things like OpenAM a framework. They are actually products. Both these work with ADFS. Be warned that it is not a trivial task to install and configure these.

Another good product is [Ping Identity](https://www.pingidentity.com/).

There's also a set of [Step-by-Step and How To Guides](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd727938%28v=ws.10%29).

Comment: So finally we managed to implement this using OpenAM. And must say was a nightmare.

Answer (score 1):

In case your are considering openam here is the link.
https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Integrate+OpenAM+with+Shibboleth

Also there are few more  links on how to install openam as IDP 
https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=688150

-Ram